# App is crashing when opening through TestFlight (Swift, iOS)

Tags: ios, crash, testflight

I have a problem, when I test my iOS App on a real device or when I testing it in the simulator all is working as expected, but when I submit the app to TestFlight and I want to open it on my device the app is instantly crashing on launch. My last changes on the app was that I added the option that the user can pick another App Icon, nothing else. But now the app is crashing in TestFlight. Anybody has an idea what I can do?

Sometimes I get this error:

> <NSError: 0x28227d6e0; domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain; code: 3 (OperationFailed); reason: "XPC error received on message reply handler">;`and this`Multiple RBSRunningReasonAttribute provided: 13 vs 20254. First one wins, but client should be fixed for assertion 31-112-6223`

I already tried to changes Scheme to Release but nothing changes still works on the simulator and the real device.